# How can I add a class atribute to django auth login form?

Tags: django, python-3.x, authentication

I've just installed Django's default authentication app. It is working and everything but I am wondering how I could change the CSS of the form.

Say I have this:

```
<form ...>
    <input type="text" class="input-class" placeholder="user">
    <input type="submit" value="login" />
</form>
```

...which would show a pretty form following the class in the text input.

But currently I have the simple ugly *login.html* template for Django auth:

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'login' %}">
{% csrf_token %}

<div>
   <td>{{ form.username.label_tag }}</td>
   <td>{{ form.username }}</td>
</div>
```

What I want to do is to get the second form with the CSS classes of the first.

Is there a way of doing so without messing with models and forms?
And, if not, can someone please show me the way?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I wish there was a straightforward way to do it, without messing with forms or installing a third-party app. But, unfortunately, that's not the case.

If you don't want to install any app, you could extend the `AuthenticationForm`:

```
class PrettyAuthenticationForm(AuthenticationForm):
    class Meta:
        widgets = {
            'username': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'input-class'})
        }
```

Then, if you are using the [`LoginView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.LoginView), pass your new `PrettyAuthenticationForm` using the `authentication_form` parameter (see the link for more details).

But I don't know if it's worth all the trouble. I've done it a few times, but usually I prefer installing [django-widget-tweaks](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/2015/12/04/package-of-the-week-django-widget-tweaks.html) or [django-crispy-forms](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

If you only need to add some css class here and there, and you are using a custom css set, I would suggest using the **django-widget-tweaks**.

If you have several forms, and you are using some CSS framework like Bootstrap or Foundation, I would recommend using **django-crispy-forms**.

An example with **django-widget-tweaks**, first install it:

```
pip install django-widget-tweaks
```

Add it do your **settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # ...

    'widget_tweaks',
]
```

In your template, load it on top of the file:

```
{% load widget_tweaks %}
```

Then use it on your fields:

```
{{ form.username|add_class:'input-class' }}
```

Comment: django-widget-tweaks worked well for me - many thanks